# Possible to change particular collection RU on database level throughput provisioned?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Can we temporarily increase/decrease the RU for a particular collection as per the need on **"existing database level throughput/RU provisioned"** cosmos db?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can change it in c# via,

```
var offer = client.CreateOfferQuery()
    .Where(r => r.ResourceLink == collection.SelfLink).Single();
offer = new OfferV2(offer, newthroughput);
client.ReplaceOfferAsync(offer);
```

Anyhow there is an opened request to [`Autoscale Throughput (UR/s)`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/16598674-autoscale-throughput-ur-s), which is **`InProgress`**

Comment: So likewise can we change throughput of database also?